# Kubernetes does not show all the component status

Tags: kubernetes

Why the property **STATUS** does not show?

```
kubectl get componentstatuses 
NAME                 AGE
scheduler            <unknown>
controller-manager   <unknown>
etcd-2               <unknown>
etcd-3               <unknown>
etcd-1               <unknown>
etcd-4               <unknown>
etcd-0               <unknown>
```

I am missing also the property **MESSAGE** and **ERROR**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see all the details, you can do:

```sh
kubectl get componentstatuses -o yaml
```

This outputs the YAML representations of the objects with all the properties whereas the default `kubectl get` output format outputs only a selection of the properties.